# Error Running Golang in 64 bit Raspian Virtual Machine

Tags: go, raspbian

I trying to install and run Golang in a 64 bit Raspbian server that is running inside an Oracle VirtualBox VM. When I try to run a program in go (merely a basic hello world program), I get the error of "/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: no such file or directory".

Have I installed go incorrectly? Or is the problem more complicated than that?

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: Are you trying to compile the program, or run an executable you already compiled?

Comment: I guess the machine on which you've compiled your executable image file has a more recent OS release than that running in a VM. I'd guess the OS in a VM has `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.2` or even `.1`. (That digit encodes the major version of the library.)

Comment: OTOH, the three most recent Raspbian releases all contain `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`, so I'm a bit at a loss here. That file is a part of the `libc6` package which, I think, is essential and must be installed.

Comment: Do you need cgo? Can you just build a static go binary and not worry about the host linker?

Comment: Or perhaps rebuild go from source on that machine.

Comment: I am trying to compile Helloworld.go, /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 is not in my VM, which installing libc6 again does not fix.